# Database design about two type users requester and technician

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have two table to login all users (`tbl_technician` and `tbl_requester`). I had to split users in two tables because I have a third table (`tbl_request`) that use both of foreign key. My model like this:

```
tbl_technician
------------
id
name
username
password
role_id
```

and

```
tbl_requester
-------------
id
name
username
password
```

and

```
tbl_request
-------------
id
title
description
requester_id
technician_id
solution
```

Now what should I do? Should be two in separate tables or in one with a column named "user_type" where I can mark it as Technician and Requester? What are the pros and cons for both? Is there a best practice for this? Also pay attention to `tbl_request` in your answer.

thanks

Comment: A user is a user and should be in a `users` table. "Requester" and "Technician" are roles played by a person. A person has many roles.

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow, a Technician will make a Request.  Then what?

There are "Users".  That is one table, with name and pwd, but not role.

The Request `JOINs` to Users twice.  And if you can't make `FOREIGN KEYs` work, then abandon them, but keep their indexes.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. can you answer clear? also request just create by requester